# range.values in loop copying blank values

Tags: excel, vba

So I created a rate calculator that allows the user to enter answers for questions pertaining to the rater ("r_user_interface").

These answers are linked to a table that has various calculations that gives the final result in the cell called ("v_premium")

The problem is, I now want to set default choices in order to compare the rates through all the zip codes, so what I did was create a transposed version of "r_user_interface" called "r_default_choices".

I then created a table which contains all 1106 zip codes as well as headers which pertain to the questions being asked in the user interface.

The macro then copies "r_default_choices" to the range of the table that contains the zip codes.

I now want to loop through every row in the table with the zip codes and default choices, and paste it in "r_user_interface" to get its respective "v_premium" value and paste it at the end of the row.

When I ran the below code the first time, it worked albeit slowly. However, now it does not copy over the v_premium values.

```
Sub cop_paste_values()
Dim rng As Range
Dim user_rng As Range
Dim row As Range


On Error Resume Next

Worksheets("Batch rater").Range("r_default_choices").Copy
Worksheets("Batch rater").Range("t_default_choices").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Set user_rng = Worksheets("User Interface").Range("r_user_interface")
Set rng = Range("t_default_choices_with_zip")

i = 23

While i <= 1106
    For Each row In rng.Rows
        row.Copy
        user_rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
        Worksheets("Batch rater").cell(i, 43).Value = Worksheets("Rater").Range("v_premium").Value
        i = i + 1
    Next
Wend

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Thoughts?

Comment: This is why you should not use `On Error Resume Next`.  Take that out at it will point you to the line that contains `cell(i,43)`, should be `Cells(i,43)`

Comment: Thanks Darrell, that did the trick. I also added Application.screenupdating=False to try and speed it up. Any insight on what else I can do to speed up the process?

Comment: @DarrellH - Also, adding `Option Explicit` at the top would help too.

Comment: Do you really have to loop the range every single time you move to the next row? Because this is what it's doing, start at row 23, loop the range "r_default_choices...", move to next row, loop the range again,and so on, over 1000 times you loop the range.